How to calculate z-score in VictoriaMetrics
I'm trying to calculate the z-score over the last 7 days to create an alert for detecting anomalies using VictoriaMetrics/PromQL, I'm aware of the zscore_over_time function, however I'm struggling to choose a proper lookbehind window for the inner query, these are the 2 queries I have:

zscore_over_time(sum(rollup_rate(m[1d], "avg")) by (x)[7d])
zscore_over_time(sum(rollup_rate(m[5m], "avg")) by (x)[7d])

Of course they have different results, since the lookbehind for the rollup_rate is different, in this situation, how exactly does zscore_over_time work, will it try to extrapolate the values since the lookbehind window for the rollup_rate is less than 7 days? If that's the case, is it better to have a bigger lookbehind window for the rollup_rate (for example, 1d) to have more accurate results for the z-score function?
Thanks.

It looks like a misconception of how [1] subqueries work. You're skipping the execution interval in query zscore_over_time(sum(rollup_rate(m[1d], "avg")) by (x)[7d:]). When skipped, it will be automatically filled with the step param (which defaults to 5min if not specified). So in result, sum(rollup_rate(m[1d], "avg")) by (x) will be executed 7d/5m times, and each of this times it will calculate rollup_rate(m[1d], "avg") on 1d interval. This is an overkill. You need to adjust inner and outer intervals.
[1] https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#subqueries

When in doubt how subquery works - try executing them with Trace enabled in VictoriaMetrics UI. Query planner will show exactly how the query is broken down by parts and with what params they're executed - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#query-tracing

Thanks, yes, now I understand about the step, so doing zscore_over_time(sum(rollup_rate(m[1d], "avg")) by (x)[7d:1d]) makes more sense?

Yes! It will now feed zscore_over_time func with 7 datapoints: rollup_rate(m[1d]) executed 7 times with 1d step.

Thanks @hagen1778, I ended up changing the query to use zscore only, as it makes more sense to get the rate over the last 7d to calculate the zscore: zscore(sum(rollup_rate(m[7d:1h], "avg")) by (x)) since I'm planning to use this for alerting.
